# QLineEdit setSelection doesn't work

Tags: qt, paint, qlineedit

I created a custom QLineEdit for timecode (a timecode looks like this : <kbd>hh:mm:ss:ff</kbd>) edition.

It react with the keyboard and the mouse. If the user edit the timecode with the mouse (draging up/down a couple of digit) the highlighting is wrong : it select all the characters from the cursor to the end. (ie: If I drag  <kbd>mm</kbd> the selection will be <kbd>mm:ss:ff</kbd>).

In order to get rid of that, I use `setSelection(x,2)` which select only the wanted digit (verified using `qDebug() << selectedText()`) but the highlighting is still wrong : [image]

```
#include "PhTimecodeEdit.h"

PhTimeCodeEdit::PhTimeCodeEdit(QWidget *parent) :
    QLineEdit(parent),
    _tcType(PhTimeCodeType25)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(onTextChanged(QString)));
    this->installEventFilter(this);
    _mousePressed = false;
    _selectedIndex = 0;
}

bool PhTimeCodeEdit::isTimeCode()
{
    PhFrame frame;
    QString text;
    frame = PhTimeCode::frameFromString(this->text(),_tcType);
    text = PhTimeCode::stringFromFrame(frame, _tcType);

    if(text == this->text())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool PhTimeCodeEdit::eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
    case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
        _mousePressed = true;
        _mousePressedLocation = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event)->pos();
        if(_mousePressedLocation.x() > 110 and _mousePressedLocation.x() < 145) {
            _selectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else if(_mousePressedLocation.x() > 145 and _mousePressedLocation.x() < 190) {
            _selectedIndex = 3;
        }
        else if(_mousePressedLocation.x() > 190 and _mousePressedLocation.x() < 230) {
            _selectedIndex = 6;
        }
        else if(_mousePressedLocation.x() > 230 and _mousePressedLocation.x() < 270) {
            _selectedIndex = 9;
        }
        return true;
    case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        _mousePressed = false;
        return true;
    case QEvent::MouseMove:
        {
            if(_mousePressed) {
                int y = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event)->pos().y();
                PhFrame currentFrame = PhTimeCode::frameFromString(this->text(), _tcType);

                if(_selectedIndex == 0) {
                    if(_mousePressedLocation.y() > y)
                        currentFrame += 25 * 60 * 60;
                    else
                        currentFrame -= 25 * 60 * 60;
                }
                else if(_selectedIndex == 3) {
                    if(_mousePressedLocation.y() > y)
                        currentFrame += 25 * 60;
                    else
                        currentFrame -= 25 * 60;
                }
                else if(_selectedIndex == 6) {
                    if(_mousePressedLocation.y() > y)
                        currentFrame += 25;
                    else
                        currentFrame -= 25;
                }
                else if(_selectedIndex == 9) {
                    if(_mousePressedLocation.y() > y)
                        currentFrame++;
                    else
                        currentFrame--;
                }

                _mousePressedLocation.setY(y);
                this->setText(PhTimeCode::stringFromFrame(currentFrame, _tcType));
                            setSelection(_selectedIndex,2);
            }
            return false;
        }

    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

What should I do to get it right ?

Comment: Can't say anything. QLineEdit works for me. I have not enoght skills in telepathy to help you without any code from you.

Comment: Instead of using event filter, you could try using overriding `mouseMoveEvent` and `mousePressEvent` and doing your selection there. You might also have to override the `dragMoveEvent`. Right now after your selection is done in the event filter, `QLineEdit` will do its own selection in the `dragMoveEvent` or `mouseMoveEvent`. Look at the [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt-gberg/source/8af3500125a03a54dddb8c46ee709b7b8d257f27:src/gui/widgets/qlineedit.cpp) for `QLineEdit` to see how the selection is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but your `eventFilter` is strange. It conflicts with mouse processing of QLineEdit.

1. Try to `return QLineEdit::eventFilter();` in default section.
2. You didn't implement mouse tracking. You should disable it with mouse capture and overloading `mouse*Event();`. Mouse events processing should be disabled while you track manually mouse.

Reason of bug: mouse moving, that processed by QLineEdit overrides text selection that you set in eventFilter. It happens on mouse release.

Possible hotfix (dirty): implement your own slot for set selection and call it via Qt::QueuedConnection. So your direct call of setSelection will be processed after releasing of mouse.

Comment: +1 for helping, but I found a (dirty) solution overloading paintEvent and set the selected text here

Comment: You should track number of such settings carefully, because you may generate infinite loop (repaint -> setSelection -> repaint)